# create panoramic view android

Tags: android-layout

I want to create a view/screen/activity in Android which has table containing ten columns. As ten columns would not adjust width-wise in the screen (would not be in readable format), I am showing 3 columns at once. 
I want to integrate a feature in the app where in if the user slids/flings on the table from right to left, the other 3-4 columns should be visible. 
This is implement in Andry Birds. If you slide the screen from right to left, remaining part of the screen is visible.
This is called panoramic view in Iphone. Can I implement this in Android.

Answer (score 2):

May be this will help http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create panoramic views on Android, you can use PanoramaGL library. The 0.1 r1 version was released today, please check http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/ and https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/wiki/UserGuide.

Comment: Hi, Is this library handles the lost of openGL context in onPause?

Answer (score 0):

Google provides [VR View](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview)

> VR view allows you to embed 360 degree VR media into websites on
>   desktop and mobile, and native apps on Android and iOS. This
>   technology is designed to enable developers of traditional apps to
>   enhance the apps with immersive content.VR view supports mono and stereo 360 images and videos. Images and video need to be stored in the equirectangular-panoramic (equirect-pano) format, which is a common format supported by many capture solutions.

Comment: @Bhunesh Varma Please guide me which is best panoramagl or vr view

Comment: VR view does not support Hotspot