# How to create Panorama 360 view in Android

Tags: android, view

Panorama 360 View may be possible in IOS, is it possible in Android as well ? can anybody let me know how to create Panorama 360 view in android.

Comment: check out this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188193/create-panoramic-view-android/42159162#42159162

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must see the [PanaromaGl library](https://code.google.com/p/panoramagl-android/) for android
The supported features in version 0.2 beta are:

- SDK 2.0 to 4.2.2.
- Architectures ARM, x86 and MIPS.
- OpenGL ES 1.0 and 1.1.
- Support for spherical, cubic and cylindrical panoramic images.
- Scrolling and continuous scrolling.
- Inertia to stop continuous scrolling.
- Zoom in and zoom out (moving two fingers on the screen).
- Reset (placing three fingers on the screen or shaking the device).
- Scrolling left to right and from top to bottom using the
  accelerometer.
- Sensorial rotation (Only compatible for devices with Gyroscope or
  Accelerometer and Magnetometer).
- Full control of camera including field of view, zoom, rotation,
  rotation range, animations, etc.
- Hotspots with commands.
- Simple JSON protocol.
- Creation of virtual tours using the JSON protocol or with
  programming.
- Transitions between panoramas.
- Support for events.

Comment: First of all thanks harvey, i got a sample project of Panorama 360 view, and i don't know why you was down voted.